# Python Scikit Decision Tree with variable number of outputs

Tags: python, scikit-learn, decision-tree

I'm looking to setup a [multi-output decision tree](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/tree.html#multi-output-problems) using the Python SciKit library. The problem I'm facing however is that it's not a simple "n_outputs" classification. Some samples will have 3 outputs, some 4, some 5. I'm not sure what the best way is to convey this to the library.

I'm considering using the maximum number of outputs and having a "no output" classification. So if I train a set where each sample is coerced to 5 outputs, any sample which originally has only 3 classifications would be changed to 5 by adding that "no output" classification.

Do you think that would work? Any other ways to do a multi-output decision tree with variable number of outputs?

Comment: Is the number of outputs itself part of the prediction task?  That is, given some input data, is the model supposed to use its training to predict how many outputs are necessary?  Or is the number of outputs derivable in a deterministic way from the input?  How do you, as a human, know how many ouputs a given input will have?

Comment: No, not really. I have a group of samples that I'm trying to put into categories. Some samples are in 3, 4, or 5 categories.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want not only to get the classification result, which is the most often occurring class of the training samples in the leaf node your test sample landed in, but also the classes of all other training samples of that node. If you want this, you might have to hack the predict method of the `sklearn.tree`, to return you that. A good starting point for such a hack is the github project of sklearn. The code is relatively easy to get through.

Comment: Another way to look at it is that you might want to do multiple classifiers, each one a binary predictor for a single category.  That is, instead of trying to predict the set of categories for a data point, try to predict "is this item in class A yes/no", "is it in class B yes/no", etc.  If you can identify mutually exclusive sets of categories, you could use these instead of binary predictions on each category.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you are trying to do multi-label classification, not multi-output classification. Multi-label can be most easily done by providing an indicator vector that says for each sample and each class whether they are in the class or not, so you get a binary array (0 for not in class, 1 for in class) of size (n_samples, n_classes).

Have a look at the [multi-label documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/dev/modules/multiclass.html#multilabel-classification-format) and see if that fits your use-case.